# Isolate words followed by certain word combinations

Tags: terminal

I have a dataset that looks something like what I have typed underneath. I'm working from the terminal from my Mac. I want to only keep queries that have 'nohitsfound' like query ENST00000446470.1 and remove queries that have 'length' two consecutive times or more like ENST00000382676.1. However, I don't know how to do this.

```
Query=ENST00000446470.1 Length=261 Nohitsfound Query=MSTRG.50645.1 Length=2007 Nohitsfound Query=ENST00000382676.1 Length=285 Length=94 Length=94 Length=94 Length=94 Query=ENST00000641821.1 Length=1217 Nohitsfound Query=ENST00000641436.1 Length=1821 Nohitsfound Query=ENST00000649959.1 Length=1734 Nohitsfound Query=MSTRG.50650.1 Length=245 Nohitsfound Query=ENST00000514465.1 Length=1395 Length=464 Length=464 Length=464
```

Any help is highly appreciated!

Comment: I think your example is wrong maybe you meant ENST00000382676.1? also is the dataset a file or just a string that you can paste?

Comment: That's correct I changed it and yes it's a file

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
echo 'Query=ENST00000446470.1 Length=261 Nohitsfound Query=MSTRG.50645.1 Length=2007 Nohitsfound Query=ENST00000382676.1 Length=285 Length=94 Length=94 Length=94 Length=94 Query=ENST00000641821.1 Length=1217 Nohitsfound Query=ENST00000641436.1 Length=1821 Nohitsfound Query=ENST00000649959.1 Length=1734 Nohitsfound Query=MSTRG.50650.1 Length=245 Nohitsfound Query=ENST00000514465.1 Length=1395 Length=464 Length=464 Length=464' | tr "Q" "\n" | grep Nohitsfound | grep -vwE "Length.*Length"
```

This will work assuming the char Q will not be part of the Query itself.

Explanation:

- echo is a terminal command to print to screen.
- | (called pipe) is a    form of redirection the output to the next
  command.
- tr will replace every "Q" with "\n" (which is a new line.)
- grep will leave only the rows with Nohitsfound.
- grep -vwE will remove lines that match the reg expression "Length.*Length".